# Espresso record pre-flow

Tags: android, android-espresso

Does Espresso provide a test/flow template to occurs before every test ?
This would be to charge the all data from the DB.
Obs: The load class is an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate a method with `@Before` (and not `@Test`) and this method will then be executed before every test method is run.